# JSONObject.toString() returns fragment of the data

Tags: android, json

I am getting JSON data from web service. Actually [from here](https://9c7504d4822f73bffc46d5ad2c612eb6c194e323.googledrive.com/host/0B364ILUXSyWXclFZRG9taEVKQ28). I want to save the exact text of the `result` object in SD card. The problem is, when I call `toString()` I do not get the full data in string. Please visit the link for the full result object. Here is what I get when I call `toString()` :

```
{"id":45,"cat":"Medicine","title":"Head and Neck","ca":[{"desc":"Because this is the correct ans.","opt_id":"45-1-1"},{"desc":"Because this is another correct ans.","opt_id":"45-1-2"},{"desc":"Because this is the correct ans.","opt_id":"45-2-3"},{"desc":"Because this is the correct ans.","opt_id":"45-3-3"}],"sub_cat":"Human Body","valid_from":"","questions":[{"id":"45-1","opts":[{"id":"45-1-1","text":"Good"},{"id":"45-1-2","text":"Bad"},{"id":"45-1-3","text":"So so"},{"id":"45-1-4","text":"None"}],"text":"How are you?"},{"id":"45-2","opts":[{"id":"45-2-1","text":"Dhaka"},{"id":"45-2-2","text":"Munich"},{"id":"45-2-3","text":"Sylhet"},{"id":"45-2-4","text":"None"}],"text":"Where are you?"},{"id":"45-3","opts":[{"id":"45-3-1","text":"iOS"},{"id":"45-3-2","text":"Android"},{"id":"45-3-3","text":"Firefox"},{"id":"45-3-4","text":"Other"}],"text":"What is the OS of your phone?"}],"mpq":0.5,"html":"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My Heading<\/h1><p>My paragraph.<\/p><img src='data:image\/jpeg;base64,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
```

Here is my code:

```
ChapterModel getChapterToStore(JSONObject chapterJSON){
//        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(chapterJSON.)
    //creating chapter object to save the chapter into database
    ChapterModel cm = new ChapterModel();
    try {
        cm.setIdOfServer(chapterJSON.getInt(JSONKeys.CHAPTER_ID));
        cm.setCategory(chapterJSON.getString(JSONKeys.CHAPTER_CATEGORY));
        cm.setSubCategory(chapterJSON.getString(JSONKeys.CHAPTER_SUB_CATEGORY));
        cm.setTitle(chapterJSON.getString(JSONKeys.CHAPTER_TITLE));
        cm.setValidFrom(chapterJSON.getString(JSONKeys.CHAPTER_VALID_FROM));
        cm.setValidTill(chapterJSON.getString(JSONKeys.CHAPTER_VALID_TILL));
        cm.setVersion(chapterJSON.getInt(JSONKeys.CHAPTER_VERSION));

        //filename and checksum is needed
        String fileName = FileUtils.getNewFileName(context);
        Log.i(tag, "Encoding! File: " + fileName + "\n Contents: " + chapterJSON.toString()); // -------- here I log the value
        FileUtils.writeToFile(CryptographicUtils.encrypt(chapterJSON.toString() + ""), fileName, null);
        String checksum = CryptographicUtils.getMd5(FileUtils.defaultPath + fileName);

        cm.setFileName(fileName);
        cm.setChecksum(checksum);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cm;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need the html in json?
keeping whole html as a json, I feel it useless. your problem might get solved if only you didn't get html is json

Comment: Didn't get you. I need the json data from server. And then keep the json in sd card. That's it.

Comment: So you looked in the file and what you show is exactly what's in the file?

Comment: in logcat there is a limit for printing json objects ... but you will get the total string while you parsing the json

Comment: @priyankamorisetti no you don't jst try it :D
When you try to parse other items below it, you can't too.

the problem might be arising due to too long string in json

Comment: @ Doug Stevenson yes. I have updated the Log output, please see. I'm Logging only the `result` object

Comment: @priyanka morisetti, no I don't get. I have parser which produces exception because of the broken json

Comment: @ Armas Cyndromic I think I am missing something. People use toString() for bigger files aslo :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jsongObject.toString()` is ok, dont worry about. Actually, your `String` is cut by the `Logcat` when your string.length() to long. You can use below method to log all your string:

```
final int chunkSize = 2048;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += chunkSize) {
     Log.d(TAG, s.substring(i, Math.min(s.length(), i + chunkSize)));
}
```